# Generate SQL in Python

Tags: python, sql

there is following DB table (example):

```
+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------+---------+
| main_name |  from   |   where    |       time        |    field    | measure |
+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------+---------+
| Students  | table_s | source = 4 | current_date - 1  | students_id | count   |
| Students  | table_s | type = 5   | current_date - 1  | students_id | count   |
| Students  | table_s | age = 20   | current_date - 1  | students_id | count   |
| Teacher   | table_t | source = 6 | current_date - 30 | b           | sum     |
| Teacher   | table_t | type = 6   | current_date - 30 | b           | sum     |
| Teacher   | table_t | age = 40   | current_date - 30 | b           | sum     |
+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------+---------+
```

What i need to generate **SQL** queries from this table in **Python**

```
SELECT COUNT(students_id)
FROM table_s
WHERE source = 4
      AND type = 5
      AND source = 20
      AND date (date) = current_date - 1
```

My thoughts so far are:

1. Transform table data to dict
2. Generate SQL Queries using a [**Jinja Template**](https://github.com/hashedin/jinjasql)

I am a beginner in Python
Thanks up front for the help :)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Also, please indicate which column identifies what should become a single query. Likely it is the `main_name` column, but it helps to be sure.

Comment: @Corion  **main_name** is identifies a single query

Comment: @Corion I need a hint with the implementation. Thx a lot

Comment: This is highly subjective. Personally, I would first collect all where clauses for a query and then put them into a dictionary together with the other parts, and then just build the string directly instead of using Jinja - using a template engine feels like overkill what is simple string concatenation.

Comment: @Corion May be it's another question, but how to transform it to **dict** that it will be useful to build query
It should look like `{'students': {'from':[tables_s] , 'where':[source = 4, type =5 , age=20], 'field' = [students_id], 'measure' =  [count]}`?

Comment: Look at your course material, it should cover how to convert data structures. Unless you show some relevant code, I can't help you here.

Comment: @Corion, got it , thank you